# validation on multiple text fields and making other controls on the screen Inactive

Tags: ios

I am having multiple textfields in my screen. I am receiving a JSON response named as validation for all the text fields. What I actually want is that I should be able to set the validation for these text fields as soon as the user is not in the range of normal values. i have prepared a logic for that: The code is as follows

```
     - (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;{
// Here we are checking if TextField is not equals to blank then we are performing 
 validations here.
if (![textField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    NSLog(@"%@",textField.UID);
    NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"column_name == %@",
     textField.UID];
    NSArray * arr = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    arr = [arr_vitalvalidations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    for (int i=0; i < [arr count]; i++) {
        NSString * str_maxValue = [[arr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"max_value"];
        NSString * str_minValue = [[arr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"min_value"];
        if ([textField.text floatValue] > [str_maxValue floatValue] || [textField.text 
       floatValue] < [str_minValue floatValue]) {
            NSString * str_message = [[arr objectAtIndex:i]
        valueForKey:@"message_note"];
            str_message = [str_message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%1" 
        withString:str_minValue];
            str_message = [str_message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%2" 
        withString:str_maxValue];
            DisplayAlert(str_message)

            [textField becomeFirstResponder];
            return NO;

        }
    }

}
return YES;
```

}

This code actually makes the other textfields dormant as now I can't switch to the Other textfields until I put the right values in the First textfield. I too have other controls on my screen but they are working fine. for example a Segment controller to change the value of Height in cm to feet. This segment controller is still working and is rightly so changing the values which I have to prevent. Moreover on pressing the Back button in order to leave this screen this code shows the Alert message  4 times. Please help me in resolving this issue. A little help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it my answer  helpful to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for solving your problem try like this it'l helps you but i don't know is it correct way or not.
   take one global variable and update the value and compare that value in textFieldShouldEndEditing
 method and perform the operation as you want.

```
-(IBAction)backBtnAction:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"close down ");
    n=10;
    [textfield resignFirstResponder];

}
```

replace your condition with below line

```
if (![textField.text isEqualToString:@""] & n!=10)
```

Comment: :- This solution will create certain further problems in my application. if somehow I can display an alert message on the click of back button and doesn't allow the app to go back by comparing it with some global variable then it will be quite feasible to me I think. Can u provide this type of functionality then it will be very good! well! thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 1):

give some image of your screen. also, y would u want to restrict user interaction because user has not entered a correct field?

PS: I cannot comment, that is why i am putting this as an answer

Comment: I am having certain medical values like "bp" or something to be entered in those textfields and therefore I have to have those validations on the textfields. I can't show u the screen as it is a enterprise app and sharing the design is out of the company policy! Hope You understand mate.

Comment: I have solved the second part of the problem i.e now it is not showing the Alert view four times but the problem of segment control is still persisting can somebody suggest a way to overcome that?